# Назначить подсветку синтаксиса типу файла в Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, синтаксис

Есть файл `.jsx`, то как назначить ему по умолчанию подцветку синтаксиса *javascript* в *Eclipse*. Или хотя бы просто переключить на время работы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Window → Preferences → General → Content Types*, там добавить `*.jsx` в нужный раздел:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]